# How to Add Products Stored in a different table in Magento DB to Magento Cart?

Tags: mysql, database, magento, paypal, shopping-cart

Can someone provide some guidance as how we can add products stored in a different Magento DB Table (as opposed to the table in which generally store products) to Magento Cart so that we can utilize the Magento Payment flow?

here is the problem:

A developer I have hired is trying to integrate a feed from a digital distributor to a Magento instance. He is saving the product info in a table in DB other than the table where Magento usually stores the products.  Actually digital products are stored at suppliers servers.

The flow of the product purchase is the following:
•   For Each Sale

1. sell the product
2. present receipt page
3. accept download hit
4. perform 'mkfu' hit

   - The important part is that when your customer follows such a link then a function on examville.com should look up the SECURITY_REFERENCE for the digital good (e.g. MTE0NjUwNzU4239xNi43NDcyOTk) and then perform a hit on the warehouse server
5. process the result
6. redirect buyer to 'fu' (fulfillment URL)

Answer (score 0):

You need to hire right developers ;)
There are no way to add such products to cart. You need to transform them to Magento products.

Comment: Thanks!  I am under a bit of time constrains.  So instead of starting from scratch again, do you have any suggestions as to a way we can transform the feed products to Magento products?

Comment: you may use Magento import tool or ask any developer to write tool speccially for your needs.